# I can't open Sony A58's RAW files on Photoshop CS6 with Camera Raw 7.1 — what can I do?

Tags: photoshop, raw, sony, adobe-camera-raw, sony-alpha

I can't open my A58's raw files (.awr) on photoshop CS6 (Camera Raw plugin 7.1) is there any chance to update my camera plugin manually or convert the file?

Comment: > raw files (awr) -- arw, to be pedantic

Comment: See also: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65030/why-dont-lightroom-or-pse-recognize-cr2-files-from-my-canon-7d-mk-ii-even-thoug/65036#65036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Adobe's [Camera Raw Supported Cameras page](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html), the A58 requires Camera Raw version 7.4

According to their [Compatible Adobe applications](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html) page, CS5 only supports ACR plugin version 6 (6.0-6.7).  Are you using CS6?  If so, should be able to update camera raw as high as version 8.71, according to that page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to convert them with the adobe dng converter.