# Do I lose dynamic range or detail when converting from CR2 to DNG?

Tags: canon, raw, canon-60d, dng

I have CS5.1 which does not support Canons RAW format using Camera RAW on a 60D, so I must change to DNG format before using CS5.1

Do I lose any quality or dynamic range from this conversion?

Comment: Your question and concerns have been previously raised and answered - Please click on this link for further information - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6188/do-i-lose-anything-converting-to-dng?rq=1

Comment: The 60D has been around for a while... Check if you have any update for Camera RAW that would make it support newer cameras.