# Can I get original JPEG image from CR2 file format?

Tags: canon, raw, photo-editing, jpeg

I am not professional photographer , but i have a professional camera (Canon).

I had shoot my pre wedding photos with this camera. So when i was open , it will be converted into black and white after few second. So I found it is 
**cr2** format.

I don't know the photo editing, so what i have to do with this format.

> ***How i can convert into jpeg format with same quality.***

Some online converter can not revert actual image.

Comment: Shoot in RAW+JPEG. Or use Canon Digital Photo Professional

Comment: Are you asking how to get the pictures with color? The data needed to process into color is still there in the raw files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The files are in RAW-format, which is actually great if you are going to post process them! Although, if you simply want to convert them to jpeg, as close to what your camera woud have possibly done, you should use Canons editing tool "Canon Digital Photo Professional" aka "DPP". Here you can do lots of stuff (I'll be posting a link below) including converting your images to jpeg like your camera would have.

http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/product/canon_software/inside_digital_photo_professional.do

Comment: Canon Software is Convert exactly Raw file to JPEG format. This is Perfectly work for me.

Comment: I'm developer of https://raw.pics.io. If you don't want to install any CR2 converting software to your computer, it's possible to use online converter to get JPG.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is a bit unclear, it sounds like you may have shot the photos with the camera set to B&W? To do this with a Canon camera one selects the *Monochrome* picture style. Or maybe you shot the images with another picture style setting that rendered color images on the camera's preview screen but now when you open them in a raw editing application on your computer they are being rendered in B&W?

Either way there are a couple of things you should keep in mind about the difference between the main information stored in the raw file and the jpeg preview image produced by the camera and displayed on the camera's LCD at the time you take the photos:

- Regardless of what photo style and other in-camera development settings are chosen when you take the picture, *all* of the data collected by the sensor is saved to the raw file. The development settings (white balance, contrast, saturation, etc.) are saved on the side as a list of ways to interpret the raw data, but *all* of the data collected by the sensor is still contained in the actual raw data.
- The picture you see on the back of your camera is not the raw data. It is a preview image that is a jpeg developed by the camera from the raw data using the in-camera development settings at the time the image was taken. This jpeg preview image is also attached to the .cr2 file but is in a separate part of the file from the raw data that was collected by the sensor.
- What you see when you open the images on your computer may be one of several things depending on the application your are using to open them and the default settings that have been selected for that application. You may be seeing the jpeg preview. You may be seeing the raw data *as interpreted by the application's default rendering profile*.

**Here is the good news: As long as you have the original .cr2 file you still have the information you need to edit the photo in whatever way you wish: B&W or color. The information you need to do either one is still in there. You just have to tell the application you're using to develop/edit the image to render it the way you want to.**

How you can specifically do that is a little broad for a single question here without knowing exactly what application you are using to edit your images. If we knew what Picture Style you shot with and what application you are using as well as the default profile being used to open the images we would be able to help you in more detail.

Some of the most popular applications used to edit .cr2 images are Adobe's *Lightroom* and *Photoshop*, both of which use the Adobe *Camera Raw* engine under the hood to develop raw image files, and Canon's own *Digital Photo Professional*. Others include products from Corel (*Paintshop Pro*), DxO (*DxO Optics Pro*), Phase one (*Capture One Pro*), and On1 (*On1 Raw*).

I personally prefer Canon's *Digital Photo Professional* for the precise color control it allows and the resulting color that one can get from Canon .cr2 files using it. Many others prefer other editors. In the end it all comes down to which works best for what you want to do with your images.

Comment: It is helpful information to understanding the whole process. This give me the better clearity.

Answer (score 0):

You open your CR2 files (RAW format) directly in Windows 10. All you need is the codec pack, which you can find here:
[Microsoft Camera Codec Pack (16.4.1734.1104)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829)

When you have it installed, open CR2 photo in Windows Photo Gallery, use Duplicate/Save option to save it as JPEG with default settings. It will not guarantee best quality of final JPEGs, and you could achieve much more by actually processing your CR2 files (exporting them to JPEG via appropriate application). Do not delete your CR2 files - hopefully you will find some time in future to develop them correctly to quality JPEGs.

Alternatively, you can use some online converter to save CR2 files and JPEG, example:
[raw.pics.io](https://raw.pics.io/convert-cr2-to-jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

You could also download a one month free trial of Adobe Lightroom which will allow you to convert your CR2 files to JPG, TIFF, DNG, PNG or whatever you want. I'd keep your original CRT archived or convert it to DNG which retains all the original info but isn't proprietary as Canon's CR2 or Nikon's NEF files. Lighroom has some good presets for B&W and color correction that you can use if you are not familiar with color correction and general tuning of images.

Comment: *All* of the info in a .cr2 is *not* retained in a .dng. Please see the answers as well as the extensive comments to several of the answer to [Do I lose anything converting to DNG?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6188/do-i-lose-anything-converting-to-dng)