# Why doesn't Adobe DNG converter recognize files from my new camera?

Tags: raw, sony, dng, adobe

I want to convert ARW files of A7III in adobe DNG converter but unable to do it.
It is showing a prompt that no raw file is present in containing folder. But works perfectly with my A7SII raw files. Can anybody suggest me something about it?

Comment: What is the version of DNG converter you use?

Comment: [How can I open .CR2 files from a Canon 750D in Lightroom 3 when I can't afford the monthly cost of the new Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99340/15871) and [Why don't Lightroom or PSE recognize CR2 files from my Canon 7D mk II even though they are up to date?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/65030/15871) Different cameras, same issue and solution.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to upgrade your version of Adobe DNG Convertor. The reason is camera vendors make slight changes in RAW formats of (almost) every new camera they release. And Adobe every several months release new version of DNG Convertor where is included support of new cameras (beside other changes).

The same is true for RAW processor of Lightroom, Adobe Camera RAW plugin for Photoshop.

You can download last version of Adobe DNG Convertor from [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/bg/photoshop/using/adobe-dng-converter.html). (no affiliate with Adobe)